# How to remove old subdomain from Google bot

Tags: django, web-crawler, google-search-console

I can't seem to find an answer to this question.

I had an old subdomain, lets say asdasd.example.com

This subdomain site no longer exists. However, I keep getting error emails from Django about invalid httphost:

> SuspiciousOperation: Invalid HTTP_HOST header (you may need to set ALLOWED_HOSTS): asdasd.example.com

Since the subsite no longer exists, I cannot use `robots.txt`.

So how can I stop the crawler from trying to index this page that no longer exists?
It doesn't just try to index asdasd.example.com but also asdasd.example.com/frontpage and other urls, which used to be valid.

Comment: Seems your dns is still configured for this domain, otherwise Google would not reach your site. Does the old domain still resolve?

Comment: Or do you catch all subdomains? In that case this page is worth reading: http://www.wellfireinteractive.com/blog/multi-tennancy-in-django-using-subdomains/

Comment: Thanks, het.oosten - will take a look at that.
And yes, we catch all subdomains (it's a kind of CMS, so subdomains  are created constantly).

Comment: I am sure you could do this also in your server config (Apache or similar). I would advise you to ask a question on Server Fault in that case.